# Strange Ghost Window

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-10

For about a month I have been getting a weird ghost window in Excel.

[image: Strange Excel window]

I can't interact with it other than clicking close or minimize. Clicking close exits the application.

It appears if I "tear" the main window and drag it into one of the standard Windows hotspots.

How can I get rid of this window?

**EDIT**

This is still occurring even with all the add-ins disabled.

Comment: When does the windows show up? Have you tried disabling all your add-ins (like Acrobat)? How about running Excel in safe mode? If you click the drop-down in the windows, what's in it?  Does it show up in your process list as a separate Excel, or other, process?

Comment: Is that a multiple monitor setup and that ghost window is appearing on your second monitor when you have excel in view? I remember Microsoft Office doing that to me once.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 yes it was the add-ins, I'll check the separate process shortly

Comment: @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere It occurs on a single monitor.

Comment: Try a repair install option for a potential quick fix. Look up resetting Excel views to default with your 2013 or whatever version you're running... Some quick starting points.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem also . . .

I've tried all the various "things to try" that many people have posted here and elsewhere . . . all to no avail.  No matter what I tried, the 'ghost' was always there IF I opened Excel full-screen (i.e. maximized).  If I had foresight of mind to close Excel non-maximized, then when I'd re-open it things were fine (no ghost).

BUT . . . . what DID work for me . . . was setting the **properties for the Excel icon** (on my Quick Launch Bar, would be same for your desktop app-launch icon) to "**[Run As Administrator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Idv0g.png)**" . . . see attached screen-shot.

Comment: If you were required to set the program to run as administrator to fix this, you didn't fix the problem you merely hid the symptoms. Excel should have no reason to run as Administrator.